# Is there a possibility to create a Cross Project Roadmap in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a possibility to track Work Items in Azure DevOps "Cross Project" wide?
So that I can get an overview over all e.g. Epics from all Projects and when they are due. (Cross Project Roadmap for specific work items).

I searched the extention Library and thought it might be able to do it over the API by pulling all work items and then combine it in an own tool.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query and and mark the "Query across projects" checkbox, then you will get a results from all the projects.

For example, a query for all done Epics in all the projects:

[image]

In this way you can query each work item field, save the queries and put the results on the dashboard, so you will have "cross projects roadmap".

Comment: Ah thank you very much. This is good to know.
But is there a possibility to depict it like for instance the Feature Roadmap extention: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension or via Azure DevOps Plans?

Answer (score 0):

Update on this Issue. The Azure DevOps Extention https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension does basically what is needed. Not completely but in some sort.